# density histogram by intervals in R

Tags: r, statistics, histogram

I want to plot an histogram with density

```
x<-c(1,15,44,40)
bits<-c(10,20,170,200)
hist(x,breaks=c(0,cumsum(bits)),right=F,freq=F)
```

This histogram doesn't plot the interval [200,400) that your density is 40/200.
What should I modify?

Comment: None of the data `x` fall in an any interval larger than 44, so the interval [200,400) should be empty. Can you elaborate on what you want to plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you have pre-binned data:

```
interval      count
[  0,  10)        1
[ 10,  30)       15
[ 30, 200)       44
[200, 400)       40
total           100
```

Your code does not work, because `hist` tries to the bin the values in `x` by itself. 1 goes to the first interval, 15 to the second and 44 and 40 to the third one.

I don't know how to do this with `hist`. With `ggplot2`, you can use the `weight` aesthetic of `geom_histogram` to do get what you want:

```
x <- c(1,15,44,40,0)
bits <- c(10,20,170,200)
breaks <- c(0,cumsum(bits))
ggplot(data=as.data.frame(cbind(bits,x)), aes(x=bits, weight=x)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), breaks=breaks)
```

In the histogram, the density for the interval is 0.002. 0.002*200=0.4=40/100.

[image: result of ggplot2]